# Viewing derived class variables while hovering the cursor over a base class pointer (C++) in visual studio code

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, ide, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to view the member variables of a derived class during debugging by hovering the cursor over a base class pointer that points to an object of the derived class.

Curious to know if visual studio code or debuggers in general support this feature.

Currently, visual studio code only shows the base class variables when I hover the cursor over the base class pointer pointing to a derived class object.